# Can boolean needle be passed to in_array?

Tags: php, boolean

Can I pass `false` as a needle to `in_array()`?

```
if(in_array(false,$haystack_array)){
    return '!';
}else{
    return 'C';
}
```

The `$haystack_array` will contain only boolean values.  The haystack represents the results of multiple write queries.  I'm trying to find out if any of them returned false, and therefore not completed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

PHP won't care what you pass in as your 'needle', but you should probably also use the third (optional) parameter for in_array to make it a 'strict' comparison. 'false' in PHP will test as equal to `0`, `''`, `""`, `null`, etc...

Answer (score 0):

Yep, just like in your example code. Because `in_array` returns a boolean to indicate whether the search was successful (rather than returning the match), it won't cause any problems.

Answer (score 0):

There's [got to be a better way](http://www.ideone.com/j9v1D).

```
<?php
    echo (in_array(false,array(true,true,true,false)) ? '!' : 'C');
    echo (in_array(false,array(true,true,true,true)) ? '!' : 'C');

Output:
   !C
```

Comment: Isn't that just a shorthand version of the code in the question?

Comment: @adam: It is indeed. My understanding of the question is "is it possible", so my answer is essentially "try it and find out". (Unless I'm reading too far/little in to the question, in which case I'll delete my answer).

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can but why don't you do it with a single boolean variable like this:

```
$anyFalseResults = false;
... your query loop {
    // do the query
    if( $queryResult == false ) $anyFalseResults = true;
}
```

at the end of the loop $anyFalseResults will contain what you are looking for.